# Getting the return of an AsyncTask and work with it?

Tags: java, android, asynchronous

I have an AsyncTask which returns a map with 2 elements. I did it like this:

```
        Map<String, ArrayList<String>> result = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();
        result.put("usernames", usernames);
        result.put("messages", messages);

    return result;
```

Now I call this Async in another Activity:

`new ReadChat().execute(response);`

How can I get the returned data in this other Activity from the Async Task (from the `doInBackground()`)?

Comment: implement the `onPostExecute`, and start a new activity from here.

Comment: Ok I found that I simply create a new Map in the Activity, call the Async and do .get() and it works, thanks anyways

Comment: Answer your own question with a correct answer or remove it.

Comment: Well but using get() it's not asynchronous anymore..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I get the returned data in this other Activity from the
>   AsyncTask?

At first i think that your question is not very clear. It depends on *"what you want to do with these data"*. AsyncTask is designated with three we can say *"main"* methods:

- **onPreExecute()** - is called before task started
- **doInBackground()** - for doing some work *"in silence"* in the background
- **onPostExecute()** - is called after doInBackground() is done

So if your `doInBackground()` method returns `Map<String, ArrayList<String>>` you can use it in onPostExecute() that takes it as parameter e.q:

```
@Override
public void onPostExecute(Map<String, ArrayList<String>> result) {
   // do some stuff
}
```

Here you can do whatever you want with result for example update your `UI` with these data, persist data with `SharedPreferences` or `SQLite`, make some next calculation, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the `ReadChat` instance somewhere. Then, set values inside `ReadChat`, wait until it finishes, then read those values back.